# How to setup Synergy across dual screen pc's

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've installed Synergy, and currently have all monitors virtually side by side. My actual setup looks like this:

[image: Multiple screens]

How can i configure Synergy to work like this

Comment: After 5 years I found a program that does this :) Power Director.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to this open Synergy issue](https://github.com/symless/synergy/issues/4173), this may not be possible to configure in a way that will make sense.  The multiple monitors on each computer are treated as one big monitor, so there is no way to get the mouse to move between the L-shaped server monitor configuration and laptop monitor 2 in a natural way.

Comment: Wow, that is extremely disappointing. Definitely a massive, massive oversight when designing this program.

Answer (score -1):

What i did was set my monitors up vertically according to windows. this being the machine i planned to host from. I have three monitors for it set up in an L on its side. so with the windows settings, my computer thinks that the single monitor in the middle is below the other two.

My work macbook and the second monitor i have for it sit above and below each other which is to the right of my windows set up. using the docs in the link below (and a little bit of math to find the percent based off my one not identical monitor XD) i set it so when you exit parts of the screen you enter others so it behaves like they are set up the way the monitors are physically set up. i'll include a snippet of my config file.

https://symless.com/help-articles/monitor-positioning-support

```
section: links
    windowsTower:
        left(65, 100) = windowsTower(0, 35)
        right(0, 29) = windowsTower(65, 100)
        right(65, 100) = workMacbook(0, 50)
        right(30, 64) = workMacbook(51, 100)

    workMacbook:
        left(0, 50) = windowsTower(65, 100)
        left(51, 100) = windowsTower(30, 64)
end
```

Comment: my setup isn't quite as complicated technically but it might be a good jumping off point

Comment: Please don't answer old off topic questions.